# wadl2java generated client throws UniformInterfaceException on successful posts and puts

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-client, wadl

The following is an example of the code generated by using the GlassFish [wadl2java](https://wadl.java.net/wadl2java.html) tool

```
public com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse putXmlAsClientResponse(com.client.BedOrder input) {
                UriBuilder localUriBuilder = _uriBuilder.clone();
                com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource resource = _client.resource(localUriBuilder.buildFromMap(_templateAndMatrixParameterValues));
                com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.Builder resourceBuilder = resource.getRequestBuilder();
                resourceBuilder = resourceBuilder.type("application/xml");
                com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse response;
                response = resourceBuilder.method("PUT", com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.class, new JAXBElement(new QName("", "bedOrder"), com.client.BedOrder.class, input));
                if (response.getStatus()>= 400) {
                    throw new OrderEntryFapi.WebApplicationExceptionMessage(javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(response.getClientResponseStatus()).build());
                }
                return response.getEntity(com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.class);
            }
```

Whenever I use the methods generated to either post or put the methods throw a `UniformInterfaceException` . The reason for this is that each method returns a ClientResponse object which should work perfectly. But instead of returning the response object itself the method calls `getEntity` which fails in the case of a `204 No Content Status code`

Other than manually modifying the generated code so that if the Status code of the response 202 I return `response` rather than `response.getEntity(com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.class)` what can I do?

Basically I'd like for all of the requests to contain a special case for 204 looking like this :

```
if (response.getStatus() == 204) {
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your WADL, Define the error statuses and what you're expecting the types to be..

```
<wadl:response status="200 204">
    <wadl:representation mediaType="application/xml"
    element="xs:SuccessResponse" />
</wadl:response>

<wadl:response status="400 401 406 415">
    <wadl:representation mediaType="application/xml"
    element="xs:ErrorResponse" />
</wadl:response>
```

This will change the generated the code to have something like:

```
switch (response.getStatus()) {
    case  400 :
    case  401 :
    case  406 :
    case  415 :
        throw new ErrorResponseException(response, response.getEntity(ErrorResponse.class));
    default:
        if (!com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.class.isAssignableFrom(returnType)) {
            if (response.getStatus()>= 400) {
                throw new OrderEntryFapi.WebApplicationExceptionMessage(Response.status(response.getClientResponseStatus()).build());
                }
            }
        }
```